# Mist RPC node error: invalid address length

Tags: mist, synchronization

Upon launching Mist, I get the following error message:

```
Couldn't connect to RPC node Error: Invalid address length, expected 40 got 4 bytes
```

I can't think of something I did over the last week that could cause this. Has anyone got a clue of what went wrong?

Best

EDIT: I have geth 1.5.3, and am on Ropsten

Comment: Could you download and try the latest geth version

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2600